# Where can I modify (at least find the files) completions in Vim?

Tags: file, vim, autocomplete

I turned on completion in Vim:

```
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete
```

Where can I modify those completions (e.g. CSS completion).
Where is the file that has those completions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On unix, it's most likely at:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim<version>/autoload/<language>complete.vim
```

and the like.

On my system it's:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim
```

On some systems it might be `/usr/local/share/vim` instead.  In Windows look in your GVim install folder.

There's also the chance that it's in `~/.vim/autoload`.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't modify these. If you want to change the autocomplete, do it from your .vim. Something like `~/.vim/after/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to know about vim's magnificent general purpose "Where the hell is that set?" command *:verbose* eg. to solve this problem you could have gone.

```
:verbose fun pythoncomplete#Complete (fun is because it is a function)
....
Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/pythoncomplete.vim
....
```

This can be used for a commands, maps, autocommands etc. eg.

```
:verbose map \t
```

should list where all key maps starting with \t

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `/home/.vim` directory and the `/home/.vimrc` file.

There seems to be several ways of implementing this.

[Here's](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2008/12/tab-completion-for-vim-updated.html) one.